# Pass offset argument in mgcv::gam() wrapper

Tags: r, scope, gam, mgcv

I wrote a wrapper function around `mgcv::gam()` to directly write the model to disk and to do some extra convenient things. So far, so good, every argument is passed on and it works. Except, when I add an offset argument to be passed on to `mgcv::gam(offset = )`. Below some example code.

```r
require(mgcv)

gam1 = function(form,
                data,
                family,
                knots = NULL) {
  gam(formula = form,
      knots = knots,
      data = data,
      family = family)
}

gam1(Sepal.Length ~ s(Sepal.Width),
     data = iris,
     family = 'gaussian')
```

Arguments are passed to `gam()` (E.g. knots, family). Works. However, if I add `offset_` to the party, it's not passed on but throws an error:

```r
gam2 = function(form,
                data,
                family,
                knots = NULL,
                offset_ = NULL) {
  gam(formula = form,
      data = data,
      family = family,
      offset = offset_)
}

gam2(Sepal.Length ~ s(Sepal.Width),
     data = iris,
     family = 'gaussian',
     offset_ = NULL)
```

`offset_` is not passed on and throws this error:
`Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'offset_' not found`. If I were to use `offset` instead, it would throw this error: `invalid type (closure) for variable '(offset)'`.

**Q: Why does my wrapper fail to pass on `offset_`? How can I make it run?**

The error happens at the last line of the source code snippet below. However I don't quite understand why.

```r
mf$drop.unused.levels <- drop.unused.levels
mf[[1]] <- quote(stats::model.frame) ## as.name("model.frame")
pmf <- mf
mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame()) # the model frame now contains all the data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is scoping.  `gam()` looks for the variables in `formula` and `offset` first in the `data` argument, then in the environment that's attached to `formula`.  Normally that would be the environment where `formula` was created; in your example that would be the global environment.

You should be able to get things to work by adding the `offset_` variable to the local copy of `data`, for example

```
gam3 <- function(form,
                data,
                family,
                knots = NULL,
                offset_ = NULL) {
  if (is.null(offset_)) {
    gam(formula = form,
      data = data,
      family = family,
      offset = NULL)
  } else {
    data$offset_copy <- offset_
    gam(formula = form,
        data = data,
        family = family,
        offset = offset_copy)
  }
}
```

If `data` has a column named `offset_copy`, this will overwrite it, so be sure to use a name that won't already be in `data`.

Edited to add:  @GavinSimpson suggested modifying the formula in his answer, to avoid problems with `predict()`.  I'd suggest a different modification than he used:  instead of deparsing the formula and offset, just modify the formula directly.  For example,

```
fun <- function(form, data, offset_ = NULL, ...) {
    ## capture what was passed to offset_, unevaluated
    off <- substitute(offset_)
    if (!is.null(offset_)) { # need to add offset
        form[[3]] <- call("+", form[[3]], call("offset", off))
    }
    ## fit and return model
    gam(form, data = data, ...)
}
```

The function `call()` creates a call, so the `form[[3]]` line replaces the RHS of the formula with an unevaluated call to `"+"` of the old RHS, and a call to `offset()` with the offset included.

The advantage of doing it this way instead of deparsing is that it should handle unusual cases properly, e.g. extremely long formulas or offsets that might deparse to several lines, or formulas where the environment is important, because this version leaves the environment unchanged.

Comment: In your code example `df` should be `data` in the second last line. Same for @GavinSimpson s answer. Edit queue is full.

Comment: Yup, that's a cleaner way than of doing formula manipulation

Answer (score 1):

@user2554330 has explained the why and how to fix it. I want to propose an alternative approach entirely.

It is better in general to include the offset in the formula. If you don't then it gets ignored in things like `predict()`.

I suggest that you add the offset to the formula if `offset_` is not `NULL`. Something like this works:

```r
fun <- function(form, data, offset_ = NULL, ...) {
    ## capture what use passed to offset_, unevaluated
    off <- deparse(substitute(offset_))
    new_form <- form # copy as we may be modifying formula
    if (!is.null(offset_)) { # need to add offset
        form <- as.character(form) # coerce to character
        ## paste some bits of the formula back together
        new_form <- paste(form[2], form[1], form[3])
        ## add the offset
        off_form <- paste0("offset(", off, ")")
        new_form <- paste(new_form, off_form, sep = " + ")
        ## coerce to formula
        new_form <- as.formula(new_form)
    }
    ## fit and return model
    gam(new_form, data = data, ...)
}
```

Here it is in use

```r
N <- 50
effort <- rep(5, N)
df <- data.frame(y = runif(N), x = runif(N), z = runif(N))
fun(y ~ s(x) + s(z), offset_ = log(effort), data = df)
```

which returns:

````r
> 
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x) + s(z) + offset(log(effort))

Estimated degrees of freedom:
1 1  total = 3 

GCV score: 0.08046669```
````

Comment: Thanks for adding, that an offset can also be set in the formula. I will directly add it to the formula now, omitting the argument `offset_` completely.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a different formula.  That adds a linear predictor `log(effort)`, when what you want (for this link) is to replace `y` by `y - log(effort)`.  For other links, it's more complicated.  However, including `offset(log(effort))` should do what you want.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you don't deparse and reparse.  Usually that works, but in a few odd cases it will fail, e.g. if the original formula got some variables from its environment instead of from data, or if the formula or offset was a really long expression that got deparsed to several lines.  I'll add demo code for this to my answer.

Comment: @user2554330 The incorrect formula is just me being silly - I'll update to wrap it in `offset( )`. I think re deparsing, the issue is more things being splint into multiple lines - the code above finds the the variables even if one is in the global environment. The problem with going the `offset` argument route is that you need more care when doing things with the model after fitting. That may not be an issue for the OP however. I was thinking about doing this via tidyeval tools as I don't think those have the same issue with splitting long expressions up.